# Access custom properties for URLs in Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7, ibm-rad

We have created a URL in websphere(V7) and created the custom properties.

**Steps to create the custom property**

Websphere Admin console => Resources => URL => URLs 
Then click on the created URL and then created the custom property.

Now we want to access this custom property from java EE application.

Can any body suggest any way to access the custom properties from java EE application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL custom properties cannot be accessed from an application.  All resource types can have custom properties that give hints to the product on how it should manage the resource.  That said, I'm not aware of any customizations for URL resources, but the console panel exists in case one gets added in the future (for example, if an APAR would require the addition of a custom property to change default behavior).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a URL Resource you also set a **JNDI** name for the resource.

You can then get the URL by making a jndi lookup:

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
URL url = (java.net.URL) initCtx.lookup("my/url/resource");
```